# How to save (not to bookmark) multiple web pages using Opera Browser

Tags: browser, automation, opera

I have HTML files containing huge lists of links to web pages

```
<OL>
<LI><A href='https://http://example.com&page=1'>page 1</A>
<LI><A href='https://http://example.com&page=2'>page 2</A>
...
</OL>
```

and I must save them all (to bookmark isn't enough), Because reasons beyond my will, I have to use Opera Browser (SO: Windows 10).

How can I mechanize the job ? I have tried DownThemAll but it doesn't see any link on the page or inside the selection (why ?!).
Can you, please, provide any advice ? Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

What I post here, while not a full fledged answer to the main question, is a trick worth sharing because considerably mitigates the typing strain.
The following AutoHotKey script saves a web page in a file, named according to a complete timestamp, by means of a single key press.

```
#NoEnv
SendMode Input  
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  

^b::
FormatTime, Time, , yyyy MM dd HH mm ss
SendInput, ^s
Sleep 2000
SendInput, %Time%
SendInput, !s
Sleep 1500
SendInput, ^w
Return
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).